# What are all the index.ts used for?

Tags: angular

I've been looking at a few seed projects and all the components seem to have a index.ts that exports * from that component. I can't find anywhere what it's actually used for?

E.g https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/tree/master/src/client/app/%2Bhome

Thanks

Comment: Relevant to this discussion is [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301) on github. You may want to read through it before using barrel files with your Angular project

Answer (score 293, accepted):

From the [Angular.io v2's archived glossary](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/glossary.html) entry for `Barrel`<sup>*</sup>:

> A barrel is a way to rollup exports from several modules into a single
>   convenience module. The barrel itself is a module file that re-exports
>   selected exports of other modules.
>
> Imagine three modules in a heroes folder:
>
> ```
> // heroes/hero.component.ts
> export class HeroComponent {}
>
> // heroes/hero.model.ts
> export class Hero {}
>
> // heroes/hero.service.ts
> export class HeroService {}
> ```
>
> Without a barrel, a consumer would need three import statements:
>
> ```
> import { HeroComponent } from '../heroes/hero.component.ts';
> import { Hero }          from '../heroes/hero.model.ts';
> import { HeroService }   from '../heroes/hero.service.ts';
> ```
>
> We can add a barrel to the heroes folder (called index by convention)
>   that exports all of these items:
>
> ```
> export * from './hero.model.ts';   // re-export all of its exports
> export * from './hero.service.ts'; // re-export all of its exports
> export { HeroComponent } from './hero.component.ts'; // re-export the named thing
> ```
>
> Now a consumer can import what it needs from the barrel.
>
> ```
> import { Hero, HeroService } from '../heroes'; // index is implied
> ```
>
> The Angular scoped packages each have a barrel named index.

See also [EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters/38000323#38000323)

---

<sup>*</sup> **NOTE:** `Barrel` has been removed from [more recent versions of the Angular glossary](https://angular.io/guide/glossary).

**UPDATE**
With latest versions of Angular, barrel file should be edited as below,

> ```
> export { HeroModel } from './hero.model';  
> export { HeroService } from './hero.service'; 
> export { HeroComponent } from './hero.component';
> ```

Comment: When I do equivalent of `export * from './hero.model.ts'`, I get a message like "'an import path cannot end with a '.ts''"  So I just change to `export * from './hero.model'`. Also worth repeating your comment about [Angular not recommending barrels anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997824/angular-2-di-error-exception-cant-resolve-all-parameters/38000323#comment66290733_38000323)

Comment: @TheRedPea thanks for the hint. I don't want to change it because it's a quote from (an earlier version of the) linked page

Comment: Do you know is there any helper library or command to generate index.js automatically?

Comment: @aokaddaoc I don't know, but I'm not using TS (only Dart)

Comment: The section of the guide you mentioned also contains a note at the very end: `You can often achieve the same result using NgModules instead.` Could you explain what they mean here, probably, with some example?

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov actually, no idea. Sounds a bit far-feched to me.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway! Just wondering if there is a better alternative to the barrels (an extra source file in every module to manage).

Comment: I guess the alternative is to just import what you need directly. Perhaps the comment about NgModule was about creating modules for "small5 parts of your application and direct imports within a module and then only import modules into each other. This should reduce the need for TS imports a lot if you split the app into modules wisely.

Comment: @AlexanderAbakumov Since a component, directive or pipe must belong to one and only one module, then by having declared any of the above in a module, when you import that module you essentially achieve the same thing... assuming you also exported them from the module.

Comment: Doesn't this, however, impose a performance drop, due to referencing modules that one doesn't necessarily need? Will this properly tree-shake?

Comment: @Qwerty I'm quite sure this works with tree-shaking, but using barrels was removed from suggested practices a long time ago, I think when modules where introduced just before 1.0.

Comment: I am not even coming from the Angular context so it was the first time to see this term, but I did have seen this practice in current javascript, so I was wondering if there are any drawbacks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Your latest comment mentions barrels have fallen out of style, and barrels are no longer in the [the current versions of the Angular glossary](https://angular.io/guide/glossary). Can I talk you into updating this answer with the current state of style & barrels, including links to discussion about barrel use ([example](https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301))? It looks like we're now meant to use "real" `NgModule`s to get what barrels used to buy us, but also that barrels are still [largely?] supported, even if no longer encouraged. Is that accurate? etc etc.

Comment: Barrels are a TypeScript thing and not specific to Angular and they often caused hard to locate errors about circular dependencies. I don't know if this is the only reason the Angular team stopped promoting them. NgModule is an entirely different beast.

Answer (score 53):

`index.ts` is similar `index.js` in nodejs or `index.html` is web site hosting.

So when you say `import {} from 'directory_name'` it will look for `index.ts` inside the specified directory and import whatever is exported there.

For example if you have `calculator/index.ts` as

```
export function add() {...}
export function multiply() {...}
```

You can do

```
import { add, multiply } from './calculator';
```

Comment: @FlowerScape Exporting via the index is particularly useful when creating libraries or module-level code, so that end users have less verbose imports. It also hides any unnecessary/confusing implementation details of the imported code.

Comment: Refactoring. You can change code, ex. rename files, as long as you keep the exports in index.ts the same.

Answer (score 9):

`index.ts` help us to keep all related thing together and we don't need to worry about the source file name.

We can import all thing by using source folder name.

```
import { getName, getAnyThing } from './util';
```

Here util is folder name not file name which has `index.ts` which re-export all four files.

```
export * from './util1';
export * from './util2';
export * from './util3';
export * from './util4';
```

Answer (score 3):

`index.ts` is usually located outside the internal folder.
E.g.:

```
my-app/
├─ src/
│  ├─ internal/
│  │  ├─ app.ts
│  ├─ index.ts
```

Assume that in `/src/internal/app.ts`, we want to import any function, e.g function A.

If we don't have the `index.ts` where we put `export * from ./internal/app.ts`, when importing function A from external, our path will go straight inside the internal folder

`import {A} from ./src/internal/app`

This should be avoided as much as possible.

If we use `index.ts`, our path is just simple

`import {A} from ./src`