# Centralised place to manage import paths

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to manage import paths in angular 2.0. I would perfer to configure it once then call it like a variable.  e.g.

```
import { ProductService } from Paths.Product.ProductService;
```

this allows me to move the folder location of the class and make one other change in the application.

Is something like this available.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564906/what-are-all-the-index-ts-used-for/37564980#37564980

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paths` property in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@Product/*": ["./path/to/product/*"]
    },
    "rootDir": "."
  }
}
```

you can then import any file inside your `/path/to/product` folder like:

```
import { ProductService } from '@Product/service';
```

and if you want to change your path, you only have to edit it in the tsconfig