# How to hide the location of components in a Angular 2 feature module?

Tags: angular, module

In a component I can use `OnInit` by importing it:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

I don't need to know the exact location of the `OnInit` source.
Angular/core has a way to hide the exact location.

I want to create a feature-module 'general' that contains interface 'MyInterface', and be able to use it in other modules by importing it like

```
import { MyInterface } from 'general';
```

What should I do to hide the exact location of MyInterface? Some index-file?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564906/what-are-all-the-index-ts-used-for

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the class/function from general in order to import them in another file.

1. Create folder "foo" with **index.ts** and **general.ts**

**index.ts**

```
export * from './general.ts';
//export * from './subfolder/otherfiles.ts';
```

**general.ts**

```
 interface A {
   myRequiredMethod(): void;

}

class B {
    anotherVariable: number = 2;

}

export { A, B };
```

**myAwesomeFile.ts**

```
import { A, B } from './foo;
class MyAwesomeFile implements A {
 constructor() { 
    const foo = new B();
    console.log(foo.anotherVariable);

 }
 myRequiredMethod() {
   //implements myRequiredMethod from the "A" interface in general.ts
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution LT56! But the problem is not to import just a component. 'General' is an NgModule. The goal it to import 'MyInterface' from the NgModule, without the need to specifiy the sourcefile within that NgModule. Similar to the way we can import OnInit from @angular/core without knowing where OnInit is within module 'core'.

Comment: I updated the code example above. You are importing the interface  "OnInit" from @angular/core.  That interface contains the method ngOnInit() which will be required to implement by any class that implements the "OnInit" interface.