# When to export what in a standalone component module?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Reviewing the code for the [angular-svg-round-progressbar](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/blob/master/src/index.ts) component.  The module definition exports the class for the `RoundProgressModule`, but also exports the services (etc) that it uses like this:

```
export * from './round-progress.component';
export * from './round-progress.service';
export * from './round-progress.ease';
export * from './round-progress.config';
```

Is this necessary?

Comment: does not appear to be necessary. The only time it is necessary is if an API is being used by the module and the exporting the API for others to use.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564906/what-are-all-the-index-ts-used-for  does this help?